# mysql inner join not work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables, let's say table "a" and "b".. both the tables have the same columns..lets say `transaction_id` and `phone_number`

here's the content of table "a"

```
buy | 1000
redeem | 1000
buy | 2000
redeem | 2000
```

and here's for the table "b"

```
buy | 1000
redeem | 1000
buy | 2000
```

when i tried to join them to find similar records, using

```
select tablea.transaction_id, tablea.phone_number
from tablea a
inner join tableb b
on tablea.transaction_id = tableb.transaction_id
and tablea.phone_number = tableb.phone_number
```

i only get

```
buy | 1000
redeem | 1000
```

the last similar record, "buy | 2000" is always missing..why this is happening?

Comment: What transaction id? what phone number?

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aa460/1. Please provide the actual data and query

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following Query. You can also use another table name instead of "a" and "b".

```
SELECT
    a.transaction_id,
    a.phone_number
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN b 
ON (a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id AND a.phone_number = b.phone_number);
```

Comment: Umm, I can't spot the difference to the OP's query. Cnould you give me a hint?